# npm install does not seem to get all dependencies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

My `package.json` looks like this (name/description/etc. omitted).

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.3.4",
        "jade": "0.34.x",
        "mongoose": "3.6.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "vows": "0.7.x"
    }
}
```

I used `express` on the repository and ran the auto-generated `node app.js`.  This worked, but when I used `curl http://localhost:port` I got the error "Cannot find module character-parser."  I ran `npm install character-parser` and then I got "Cannot find module transformers."  This happened a few more times, but after I installed all of them the app started working.

I thought that `npm install` was supposed to install dependencies recursively.  This also worries me because I obviously want the `package.json` to be usable when the app is deployed.

Comment: But npm does install recursively. After running `npm install`, are there any errors? Please post them if so.

Comment: @gustavohenke no errors, unfortunately.  It says everything is okay, but then when I try to run node I get the missing module error until I use `npm install <module-name>`.  Do I need to use `sudo npm` perhaps?

Comment: Do you have npm-shrinkwrap.json? If you do, check that the required modules are listed.

Comment: @Fluffy I had the same issue and once I removed/updated npm-shrinkwrap.json, it installed all dependencies as defined in package.json. Thank you.

Comment: @Fluffy I confirm what @tamsler have said. Check that you don't have a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in your folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple script to collect the dependencies in ./node_modules:

```
var fs = require("fs");

function main() {
  fs.readdir("./node_modules", function (err, dirs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    dirs.forEach(function(dir){
      if (dir.indexOf(".") !== 0) {
        var packageJsonFile = "./node_modules/" + dir + "/package.json";
        if (fs.existsSync(packageJsonFile)) {
          fs.readFile(packageJsonFile, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            else {
              var json = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log('"'+json.name+'": "' + json.version + '",');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });
}
```

For one project I'm working on, the output looks like this:

```
"progress": "0.1.0",
"request": "2.11.4",
```

If you remember to remove the comma from the last entry, you can copy and paste the output.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact error while I was npm installing for https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/humanjs-sample-app/

I'm on a Windows machine, so I suspected that it was an issue with the odd   restrictions that Windows has on the number of characters in a file path.

I resolved this by shorting my base path to a three character folder name in my root (in this case going from C:\projects\humanjs-sample-app to C:\hjs).  When I re-ran npm install everything worked.  I'm not happy with that resolution.  I shouldn't have to worry about my base path name being too long.  This is one of the reasons that people often don't do node development on Windows machines.

An alternate resolution is to develop on Linux or Mac, if you aren't already.  That's probably my long term strategy.

Comment: I just noticed you have an Ubuntu tag on your question, so this may not be your issue.  I won't delete this, though, just in case.

Answer (score -1):

When you run `npm install <name-of-package>` it will install the package to your `node_modules` folder, but will not add it as a dependency. In order to install the package and save it as a dependency in your `package.json`, you must use the `--save` flag like so:

`npm install <name-of-package> --save`

The [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) provides further information on additional flags that can be used such as the `--save-dev` flag for saving development dependencies and the `--save-optional` flag for saving optional dependencies to your `package.json`.